# methods in java script and calling multiple methods

Tags: javascript

why can't i call both changeBackground() and toNormal() as method from custom

when i remove toNormal as a method and place it outside custom as a stand-alone function the code works but while in custom it does not

can an object hold more than one method

> var custom =
> {
>
> changeBackground : function(){
>
> var text = document.getElementById("para").style.backgroundColor ="red";
> }
>
> toNormal : function(){
>
> var text = document.getElementById("para").style.backgroundColor ="";
> }
>
> }
>
> ```
>  this is some text
> ```

Comment: Please format your code properly, you'll see, that a comma is missing.

Comment: please also be more precise in your English text ... "as method from custom" - a custom what? banana, apple, function, object???

Comment: Check this out. https://jsfiddle.net/knm2y8sp/2/

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the `,` after your `changeBackground` function. A list of objects requires them to be seperated by a comma.

```js
var custom = {
  changeBackground: function() {
    var text = document.getElementById("para").style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }, //<-- this
  toNormal: function() {
    var text = document.getElementById("para").style.backgroundColor = "";
  }
}

custom.changeBackground();

setTimeout(custom.toNormal, 1000);
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="para"></div>
```